# Coxeter's braid group quotients

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, braid-groups

Coxeter's result is that if the generators of the braid group $B_n$ on $n$ strands fulfill a relation $\forall_i\sigma_i^k=1$, then $1/n+1/k>1/2$ must hold to get a finite quotient of $B_n$. In other words, any braid can be simplified to a finite number of "basis" braids.

Let us forget about groups for a moment. The mere "can be simplified" part should hold (I strongly assume) even if we allow instead a polynomial relation on $\sigma$ of degree $k$, say, $\sigma_i^2=\sigma_i+1$, in which case we no longer have a group, but an algebra (any braid simplifies to a member of a vector space over a finite number of basis braids).

Even more interesting from the view of knot theory would be to expand $B_n$ to $T_n$ by throwing in also the Temperley-Lieb generators $\tau_i$ (eh, how is that called, Turaev algebra?). Clearly, say, the Kauffman/Dubrovnik polynomial can be defined via $\sigma+\sigma^{-1}=A(\sigma^0+\tau)$ or via $(\sigma-x\cdot\sigma^0)(\sigma-y\cdot\sigma^0)(\sigma+1/y\cdot\sigma^0)=0$, thus a degree $k$ polynomial relation in $\sigma$ over $B_n$ should have the same "power" as a degree $k-1$ one over $T_n$. But clearly $\tau$ has much simpler relations, thus I expect that the Coxeter result can't be generalized to $T_n$: maybe all members of $T_n$ can be simplified to linear combinations of a finite number of basis $T_n$ even if $1/n+1/k<1/2$.

Handwaving argument: For $k=3$, Kauffman/Dubrovnik is associated with the Lie algebras $BCD_m$, $T_n$ "is" the vector space $V^{\bigotimes{2n}}$ ($V$ being the defining irrep of $BCD_m$), which is obviously finite for all $n$, thus throwing in $\tau$ always gives a finite quotient. But this argument already breaks down for $k=4$, as this is associated with the magic $E_7$ series only for a certain free parameter relation, but not even a Lie algebra results for the most general possible relation. ("General"="self-consistent wrt local Reidemeister moves", i.e. $(\sigma-a\cdot\sigma^0)(\sigma-b\cdot\sigma^0)(\sigma-c\cdot\sigma^0)(\sigma-(abc)^3\cdot\sigma^0)=0$; $E_7$ forces $c=-1/b^3$ or symmetric. Generally, $T_3$ has dimension 40, $T_4$ at least $950$ or so, but I couldn't prove yet that $T_4$ has a finite dimension.) Likewise for $k=5$, the $E_8$ series results only for restricted parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by “any polynomial relation on $\sigma$ of degree $k$”?

Comment: @HJRW; Well, what hinders us to replace the assumption $\sigma^2=1$ with, say, $\sigma^2=\sigma+1$? This means we now have linear combinations of braids, but the crucial point of the question is if any braid can be simplified, and simplified to a vector space over a finite number of braids (all closures, i.e. links, then have a defined value) is simplified enough for me...

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the category that you’re working in. To obtain a quotient *group*, one needs to kill group elements. The relation $\sigma^2=\sigma+1$ isn’t an equation of group elements, so it looks like you’re asking for a different kind of quotient object.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I try to rewrite.

Comment: I understand the meaning, but I can't read "I strongly assume" without thinking of "[I strenuously object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOnRHAyXqYY)" from _A few good men_. 